# WPF Points optimization

Tags: wpf, canvas, optimization, points

The answer to my question might be evident, I'd just like to have confirmation.
I have a curve with a large number of points which has to be optimized.
On that curve I might have to do various operations that are:
1. add on canvas
2. move on canvas
3. stretch on canvas
4. canvas pan
5. canvas zoom

To do that I have an original polyline which stores all the original points.
Then I have a second polyline which stores the optimized set of points.

First of all my optimization seems trivial that is:
1. points are double vars but in the end on the screen are integers. so if point1 and points2 CONVERTED TO INTEGER are the same I discard point2.
2. if a segment has BOTH start and end out of the canvas (e.g. for having panned or zoomed) I discard both points.

And I do that for all points.
This is very efficient since an example spiral with a 1million points can be reduced to some 4000 points!!

After that I always display the optimization curve.

---

Regarding the various operations performed on the curve.

2. move on canvas ---> does not require to redo the optimization (I can't move it outside the canvas). I move the secondary curve
3. stretch on canvas ---> does not require to redo the optimization. I stretch the secondary curve
4. canvas pan ---> requires redoing optimizations some points might be cut out of the canvas.
5. canvas zoom ---> requires redoing optimizations some points might be cut out of the canvas.

Is all that correct?

thanx for helping
Patrick

Comment: Screen coordinates in WPF are double values, so the convert-to-integer method should be replaced by some minimal-distance-between-points method. In general, there is the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to reduce the number of points in a polyline.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification but there still is something I can't understand. Let's talk about PHYSICAL pixels on a monitor. Let's say I have P1=new Point (0.0, 0.0); and P2 = new Point (0.001, 0.001). I am aware that for WPF those are different but in short are they DIFFERENT ON THE SCREEN?

Comment: That would depend on the screen. If you had an imaginary screen with 96000 DPI, they would indeed by different. You should have an algorithm that reduces the number of points in a way that is independent on screen resolution. IMO, Douglas-Ramer-Peucker would be a sensible approach. It would result in a lot less than 4000 points, I guess.

Comment: I've read the wiki link you provided. What I can't understand is how to determinate the epsilon value. Trying to figure out what values could interfere with epsilon finding I can think of: 1. canvas size, 2. monitor resolution 3. monitor maximal resolution. But from that onwards how to calculate epsilon?

Comment: If the point coordinates are screen coordinates (e.g. values in range 0 .. ~1000), an epsilon of 1 would be a good start. You may however play around with the epsilon value to find an optimal solution. I've shared my implementation in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [Douglas-Ramer-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to reduce the number of points in a polyline:

```
public static IList<Point> ReducePoints(IList<Point> points, double tolerance)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>(2);

    indexes.Add(0);
    indexes.Add(points.Count - 1);
    ReducePoints(points, tolerance, indexes, 0, points.Count - 1);

    return indexes.OrderBy(i => i).Select(i => points[i]).ToList();
}

private static void ReducePoints(
    IList<Point> points, double tolerance, List<int> indexes, int first, int last)
{
    if (first + 1 < last)
    {
        var dx = points[first].X - points[last].X;
        var dy = points[first].Y - points[last].Y;
        var length = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var maxDistance = 0d;
        var farthest = 0;

        for (var index = first + 1; index < last; index++)
        {
            var dxi = points[first].X - points[index].X;
            var dyi = points[first].Y - points[index].Y;

            // perpendicular distance from line segment first to last
            var distance = Math.Abs(dx * dyi - dxi * dy) / length;

            if (distance > maxDistance)
            {
                maxDistance = distance;
                farthest = index;
            }
        }

        if (maxDistance > tolerance)
        {
            indexes.Add(farthest);
            ReducePoints(points, tolerance, indexes, first, farthest);
            ReducePoints(points, tolerance, indexes, farthest, last);
        }
    }
}
```